# Save Function Result Into a Variable

Tags: php, jquery, function

I have this function, which loads a select from a database.

```
function Competition() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "load-comp.php",
            cache: false,
            success : function(html) {
                // something here
            }
        });
        EditRow();
    });
}
```

I need to put that select inside confirmEdit (in the second td).

```
EditRow() {
    var confirmEdit = '<tr class="editable" id=" '+ id +' ">
                         <td><input type="text" value="' + name + '" /></td>
                         <td> ' + /* function result goes here */ + ' </td>
                         <td><input type="text" value="' + data + '" /></td>
                         <td>' + saveCancel + '</td>
                       </tr>';
}
```

So how do I save the result produced by the Competition() function inside a variable so I can use it in the EditRow() function?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly why don't you just call EditRow() from inside the success portion of the ajax call and pass in the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Competition() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "load-comp.php",
                cache: false,
                success : function(html) {
                    EditRow(html);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Ryan's comment is correct. In your original EditRow may be called before the load-comp.php is retrieved.

Answer (score 3):

Your data comes back from `load-comp.php` in the variable name of "html". So you could modify the EditRow function and pass it that "html" variable (you might need those other variables too)

```
function EditRow(html, id, name, data, saveCancel) {
var confirmEdit = '<tr class="editable" id=" '+ id +' ">
                         <td><input type="text" value="' + name + '" /></td>
                         <td> ' + html + ' </td>
                         <td><input type="text" value="' + data + '" /></td>
                         <td>' + saveCancel + '</td>
                       </tr>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is, by definition, asynchronous.  `EditRow` might be called before your Ajax call completes.  Why not put the call to `EditRow` in the success function of the Ajax call?  That's the only way you can guarantee the function only gets called after completion of your Ajax.  Once you do that, then you can just pass the result in as a parameter to the `EditRow` function.

Change `EditRow` to:

```
function EditRow(html) {
  var confirmEdit = '<tr class="editable" id=" '+ id +' ">'+
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + name + '" /></td>'+
    '<td> ' + html + ' </td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" value="' + data + '" /></td>'+
    '<td>' + saveCancel + '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
}
```

and then change your `ready` function to:

```
function Competition() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "load-comp.php",
      cache: false,
      success : function(html) {
        EditRow(html);
      }
    });
  });
}
```